# jquery AJAX response in plain ASCII

Tags: ajax, jquery

I post a pair of chinese characters to my server:

> 忠孝

the web server then translates them into pinyin:

> Zhōngxiào

I know this works, because I got that by directly hitting my AJAX handler. So, the server is encoding everything correctly. However, when I receive that response via jQuery, I get:

> Zh&#333;ngxi&#224;o

My code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", url: 'procChineseTrans', data: 'toTrans='+text,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    complete: function(data){
        //alert(data.responseText);
        $('#street_address').val(data.responseText);
}});
```

I also set:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Is there a reason my response is in plain ASCII?

Edit:

Checking my response header, it says it is in UTF-8. But, it is still displaying ASCII

Comment: I don't think you've got a jquery problem...something on the server-side is producing that HTML-escpaed text and jquery's just going to roll with it.  Btw, there's no content-encoding value that can force HTML escaping.

Comment: Server-side it seems fine. When I hit my handler directly, it encodes it correctly...

Comment: Have you used a debugger to inspect the value in `data.responseText` or are you just seeing the result after it's been set to your `#street_address` element?

Comment: Yup, check via firebug. Same.

Comment: @stevevls I actually did just notice something. In the Response tab of Firebug it is giving me the ascii, but in the HTML tab, it is giving me the correct utf8 encoded text.

Comment: @Ginamin I think I figured out what's going wrong...have a look at my answer.

Comment: @stevevls I just also tried replying with straight Chinese and it displays it fine. It just seems to be pinyin it has a problem with... curious.

Comment: Seems I found a work around. By using .html() it formats it correctly. So I set a hidden div and set the content via html(), then alerted that and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forced it to into html() which formatted it.

Answer (score 1):

Aha...I see what your problem is.  The `text/html` header you're sending back is causing jquery to parse the `responseText` as HTML.  When you don't specify the `dataType` option, jquery makes a best guess as to what type of data you're playing with based on response headers.

Try adding `dataType : text` to the options in your `$.ajax` call.  If that works, then think about adjusting the response `Content-type` header.

For further reading, search for "dataType" in the jquery manual page : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Tried changing the datatypes and stripping out the header. Didn't work. Firebug is still posting the ascii string in response, and the utf8 formatted in the html tab.